# Auto conversion type - Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and I would like to know if there is any way to *implicitly* convert an object.

By implicitly, I mean, for example, writing something like this :

```
MyColorClass *color = [[MyColorClass alloc] init];
SomeStuffUsingUIColor(color);
```

Instead of this :

```
MyColorClass *color = [[MyColorClass alloc] init];
SomeStuffUsingUIColor([color toUIColor]);
```

I know that there is no way to overload casting operators (in Objective-C), but maybe there is a specific solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's often no need to *convert* the object to a new type. Just implement the same methods that UIColor does, so that MyColorClass responds to the same messages. This isn't *always* enough -- for example, if MyColorClass isn't a UIColor subclass, it won't get any methods added to UIColor via a category. If you need that, it's best to derive MyColorClass from UIColor so that every instance of the former *is* an instance of the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to create a category for this kind of things, e.g.

```
@interface UIColor (MyExtensions)
- (void)doSomethingUsingColor
@end
```

```
@implementation UIColor (MyExtensions)
- (void)doSomethingUsingColor {
  //do something
}
@end
```

You can see some examples in `NSString+UIStringDrawing.h` category.

Also note that if you want to do something with a C struct, you would usually declare a function, e.g.

```
typedef struct {
   int x;
   int y;
} MyPoint;
```

```
void doSomethingWithPoint(MyPoint point) {
   //do something
}
```

You can see examples in the API, for example: `NSStringFromCGPoint`.